# Handling donations on Google Play without Google Merchant

Tags: android, paypal, google-play, donations

I have a free app on Google Play, and I'd like to add a donate button to it. I tried to create a Google Merchant account but it required a business name and address that will be shown to public. I'm a single developer and I don't have an address other than my home address, so that's not an option.

I've also read here that some apps have been suspended/pulled from Google Play due to using direct paypal access. Maybe writing one's paypal email and asking users to use it to donate is an (although absurd) option.

To sum up, how do you handle donations on Google Play if you're not a business entity? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution but it seems that nobody is using it. Also, no trace of the word _donation_ in the Google Play Documentation. I've found this lib: `https://github.com/sufficientlysecure/donations` but is it legal ? If we use it, do we risk to be suspended ? I even asked `googleplay-developer-support@google.com` but I got an auto-answer that sent me to `http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/` where... I lost my self...

Comment: I've found this: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

 **Wallet** - You can now enable donations from your Android app in the same way you enable purchases. To do so, create a WalletFragment and specify the BUY_BUTTON mode, then set the button text to DONATE_WITH_GOOGLE. **Note**: Use of the _Donate with Google_ button is limited to 501(c)(3) organizations. For more information, see the Content policies.

Comment: This brings to https://support.google.com/wallet/business/answer/75724?hl=en&rd=1

**Unacceptable product categories**: _Fund solicitations_

**Examples**: Donation solicitations from parties without a valid 501(c)(3) tax exempt status clearly displayed to the public; solicitations from parties without valid proof of exempt tax status or proof of registration with the relevant country's regulatory bodies and authorities; and political organizations that have registered with the FEC

Comment: New: https://developers.google.com/donation/